# How do I perform a basic scipy gridddata interpolation using plpython?

Tags: python, postgresql, scipy, plpython

Having trouble moving from [plpython documentation example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpython-database.html) and [griddata example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata) to actual working code.

Let us assume that 'my_table' has x, y, and z values for some simple reference grid where x,y pairs are point coordinates and z is the value at that point.  Input parameters are `inx` and `iny`, which define a point coordinate that we want to interpolate a `z` value for.

```
create or replace function somefunc(inx numeric, iny numeric) 
returns numeric as 
$$ 
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

# get the lookup table
refvals = plpy.execute("SELECT x, y, z FROM my_table")

points = np.ndarray(refvals['x'], refvals['y']) #nope
points = np.ndarray(refvals["x"], refvals["y"]) #nope
# ERROR:  TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

points = np.array(refvals[:,0], refvals[:,1]) #nope
# ERROR:  TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

zvals = refvals["z"] # nope

return sp.interpolate.griddata(points, zvals, (inx, iny), method="cubic");
$$ LANGUAGE plpython2u stable;
```

This doesn't work because I don't understand what's going on with refvals and how to get its elements into the appropriate data types for griddata.  I'm thinking in terms of `r` data.frames (i'd use `refvals[,c('x','y')]` to get the pairs of x,y coordinats) or `SQL` tables (i'd use `select x, y from refvals`), but the `refvals` object is something in python called a `list of dict`, which I don't quite understand how to access properly.

I gather from the syntax in the documentation `foo = rv[i]["my_column"]` that a loop (e.g., `for i = 0:len`) may be necessary?

Comment: Maybe something like `points = np.array([(row['x'], row['y']) for row in refvals])` might work (not tested)?